# Format my XML output in CakePHP

Tags: xml, cakephp

I have the `players` table with three `field id`, `first_name`, `last_name`. 
The `PlayersController` have method `index` that show every player in the table:

```
public function index() {
        $output = $this->Player->find('all');
        $this->set(array(
            'output' => $output,
            '_serialize' => array('output')
        ));
        $this->render('generic_response');
    }
```

and the generic_response is an XML view that look like this:

```
<?php
$xml = Xml::fromArray(array('response' => $output));
echo $xml->asXML();
```

The resulting XML is:

```
<response>
  <output>
     <Player>
       <id>2</id>
       <first_name>Ciro</first_name>
       <second_name>Spee</second_name>
     </Player>
   </output>
   <output>
     <Player>
       <id>3</id>
       <first_name>Ugo</first_name>
       <second_name>Ridi</second_name>
     </Player>
   </output>
</response>
```

but I want something like:

```
<response>
  <players>
     <Player>
       <id>2</id>
       <first_name>Ciro</first_name>
       <second_name>Spee</second_name>
     </Player>
     <Player>
       <id>3</id>
       <first_name>Ugo</first_name>
       <second_name>Ridi</second_name>
     </Player>
   </players>
</response>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old code:

```
$output = $this->Player->find('all');
$this->set(array(
    'output' => $output,
    '_serialize' => array('output')
));
```

New code:

```
$output = array(
    'Player' => Hash::combine(
        $this->Player->find('all'),
        '{n}.Player.id',
        '{n}.Player'
    )
);

$this->set(array(
    'players' => $output,
    '_serialize' => array('players')
));
```

Comment: I've never heard about this function, i've read the doc, and seem very powerfull. I'll let you know if it works as soon i can try the code ;)